# How to Execute Selenium Selenium Test Cases based on Excel Flag. If Yes only then run the test cases and write the Pass/Fail result in excel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one Excel file in which there is `Test Case Name`, `Test Case description`, `Data`, `Flag` and `Result`.

I want to execute only those test cases which have `Flag` set as `'Y'` and skip rest of all the test cases where `Flag` is equal to `'N'`.

Also, once executed need to write the `Status` as `Pass/Fail/Skipped`.

Is it possible to achieve by Selenium?

Any help/code would be appreciated. If someone has done this in his/her framework kindly share the logic.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you search for your question before asking it on this forum? What all have you tried till now? Paste your code here. Also go through this [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes we can do this with selenium use Apache POI for applying your Flag logic